# selectcox (Backward variable selection in the Cox regression model)

Tags: r, confidence-interval, cox-regression, survival

I use the package `riskRegression` and the function `selectCox` to conduct a backward-selection model.

```
https://rdrr.io/github/tagteam/pec/man/selectCox.html
```

```
library(pec)
library(prodlim)
data(GBSG2)
library(survival)
library(riskRegression)
```

```
f <- selectCox(Surv(time,cens)~horTh+age+menostat+tsize+tgrade+pnodes+progrec+estrec ,
           data=GBSG2)
```

Is it possible to display 95% CI?

Comment: What do you want to plot with the 95% CI?

Comment: I do get Coef  , S.E. ,  Wald Z, Pr(>|Z|) but no no Confidence Intervalls. That woud be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I did a good faith search on SO for a good duplicate to nominate but I didn't find one. I was amused that chatGPT coding was used in the prior answer on the proper component in the `selectCox` object, because it's basically re-inventing an existing function default function named `confint`. Let's first show how one should have approached this: The place to start is looking at the structure of the returned object named `f` in this case.

```
f
#----screen outputs---
$fit
Cox Proportional Hazards Model

rms::cph(formula = newform, data = data, surv = TRUE)

                      Model Tests    Discrimination    
                                            Indexes    
Obs      686    LR chi2     99.16    R2       0.135    
Events   299    d.f.            5    R2(5,686)0.128    
Center 0.526    Pr(> chi2) 0.0000    R2(5,299)0.270    
                Score chi2 115.95    Dxy      0.375    
                Pr(> chi2) 0.0000                      

           Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
horTh=yes  -0.3203 0.1257 -2.55  0.0108  
tgrade=II   0.6524 0.2488  2.62  0.0087  
tgrade=III  0.8084 0.2678  3.02  0.0025  
pnodes      0.0542 0.0068  8.01  <0.0001 
progrec    -0.0022 0.0006 -3.97  <0.0001 


$In
[1] "horTh"   "tgrade"  "pnodes"  "progrec"

$call
selectCox(formula = Surv(time, cens) ~ horTh + age + menostat + 
    tsize + tgrade + pnodes + progrec + estrec, data = GBSG2)

attr(,"class")
[1] "selectCox"
####---- end of output ---
```

So apparently there is a function named `print.selectCox` that bundles the results of calculations on the first copmponet and displays them under the heading "$fit". Now look ar the actual structure:

```
str(f$fit)

####--- somewhat more informative ---

List of 30
 $ coefficients     : Named num [1:5] -0.32028 0.65239 0.80839 0.05425 -0.00221
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "horTh=yes" "tgrade=II" "tgrade=III" "pnodes" ...
 $ var              : num [1:5, 1:5] 1.58e-02 -3.57e-05 1.55e-03 2.82e-05 -3.77e-07 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "horTh=yes" "tgrade=II" "tgrade=III" "pnodes" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "horTh=yes" "tgrade=II" "tgrade=III" "pnodes" ...
 $ loglik           : num [1:2] -1788 -1739
 $ score            : num 116
 $ iter             : int 5
 $ linear.predictors: Named num [1:686] 0.1831 0.0511 0.1795 -0.1094 0.1232 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:686] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ residuals        : Named num [1:686] 0.18 0.169 0.705 0.399 0.683 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:686] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ means            : num [1:5] 0.359 0.647 0.235 5.01 109.996
 ### snipped the remaining items in the list
```

So the first item is named "fit" and it is a list in its own right and has sub-components named `coefficients` and the second item is named `var`.

The base R function named `confint.default` can return confidence intervals from any R object with names "coefficients" and "var" as long as the second of those is a square matrix with dimensions that correspond to the length of "coefficients".  If you try using it on the entire `selectCox`-classed object it fails, if you use it on just the `fit` part is succeeds:

```
> confint(f)
Error in vcov.default(object) : 
  object does not have variance-covariance matrix

> confint(f$fit)
                  2.5 %       97.5 %
horTh=yes  -0.566648468 -0.073905052
tgrade=II   0.164830108  1.139941870
tgrade=III  0.283558082  1.333218011
pnodes      0.040965920  0.067528158
progrec    -0.003298602 -0.001117193
```

But you need to exponentiate those values to make then on the risk-ratio scale:

```
> exp( confint(f$fit) )
               2.5 %    97.5 %
horTh=yes  0.5674240 0.9287599
tgrade=II  1.1791928 3.1265866
tgrade=III 1.3278460 3.7932304
pnodes     1.0418166 1.0698604
progrec    0.9967068 0.9988834
```